# Compare lines of two files, print lines unique to first file

Tags: bash

I have two text files that contain a unique sorted list of words:

File 1:

```
a
b
c
d
```

File 2:

```
b
c
```

I need a new file that contains only the extraneous lines in File 1, so the result will be

```
a
d
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is what [`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/comm.html) is for:

> **comm** -- select or reject lines common to two files

You want

```
comm -23 "File 1" "File 2"
```

which will suppress output of *lines only in file 2* and *lines in both files*, leaving only *lines in file 1.*
More answers [here on Greg Wooledge's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -f file1.txt -vFx file2.txt
```

Notice the usage of the flags `F, --fixed-strings` and `x, --line-regexp`, to force the comparison to be performed considering the entire line.

Comment: Thanks, this also works: `sort file1.txt file2.txt file2.txt | uniq -u`

Comment: This answer doesn't require files to be sorted. More human-readable: `grep -f file1.txt --fixed-strings --line-regexp --invert-match file2.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

`$ join file1.txt file2.txt -v 1`

`$ man join`

```
-a FILENUM
   print unpairable lines coming from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2
-v FILENUM
   like -a FILENUM, but suppress joined output lines
```